# cube faces disappear

Tags: faces

I have download the file from some website and when im rotating the file some faces hide and only edges is visible. Is the file corrupted or is there setting done to the cube when rotated the faces hide.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cube has backface culling enabled. Tab into object mode, hit <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the Properties Region, then scroll to shading and untick "Backface Culling".

[image: disable backface culling]

Comment: Only one little addition: this cube represent simplified room and that's the reason why normals facing the interior, so it is good as is :-)

Comment: @Shubol3D - that's right, but it wasn't the question.